# WPF: Why doesn't my ComboBox SelectedItem show?

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

(This question has been updated)

**I have:**

- Window1 - with a `DataGrid`
- Window2 - where I create new `DataGrid` rows
- Window3 - where I open a `DataGrid` row as a profile to view its
  contents

**My issue:**

When I open Window3, the ComboBox does not display the item I selected in Window2

The ComboBox in Window2 is bound like this:

```
<ComboBox
      Text="{Binding PropertyName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
         <ComboBoxItem Content="AS">
         </ComboBoxItem>
         <ComboBoxItem Content="ASA">
         </ComboBoxItem>
         <ComboBoxItem Content="ANS">
         </ComboBoxItem>
         <ComboBoxItem Content="EPF">
         </ComboBoxItem>
</ComboBox>
```

I would prefer to keep it like that, to just hard-code in the items, as there probably won't be any more of them.

When I save it, I go to Window1, and open my freshly saved row.

The `DataGrid` `SelectedItem` is bound by property (named "Selected"), which to each object in Window3 (several TextBoxes - these work fine, and one ComboBox - does NOT work!). The ComboBox stores the data I need, but does not display my previous choice as `SelectedItem`.

The ComboBox in Window3 is bound like this:

```
<ComboBox
       DataContext="{Binding Path=(viewmodel:LicenseHolderViewModel.Selected)}"
       Text="{Binding PropertyName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
         <ComboBoxItem Content="AS">
         </ComboBoxItem>
         <ComboBoxItem Content="ASA">
         </ComboBoxItem>
         <ComboBoxItem Content="ANS">
         </ComboBoxItem>
         <ComboBoxItem Content="EPF">
         </ComboBoxItem>
</ComboBox>
```

So, the items show up in the ComboBox, but nothing is selected as default.
If I remove the `ComboBoxItem` from the XAML, the ComboBox is just empty (naturally).
I tried adding `ItemsSource="{Binding PropertyName}"` (..a shot in the dark), and that just added one of the items, split into three (E, P, F), but none of them set as `SelectedItem`.

There might be worth noting that my framework automatically couples view with the viewmodels, and me having to set another ViewModels property as each of the objects DataContext, might have caused some hick-ups? (I tried testing for that, and I can't confirm if that's the case).

Comment: *What have I done wrong?* you've assume that `string` can be automagically converted to `NameOfModel` ... obvious solution ... you should bind `ComboBox` 's `ItemsSource`  to `IEnumerable<NameOfModel>` (instead using `ComboBoxItem` ) and `SelectedItem` should be binded to type `NameOfModel` ... also instance of `NameOfModel` should be able to compare it to other instance

Comment: @Sandra: What type is `PropertyName` and what's the `DataContext` of window2?

Comment: `d:DataContext` is just a Visual Studio designer thing. It has no effect when you run the app. Did you see my answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should bind the `Content` of the selected `ComboBoxItem` to a the source property. To do this, you should bind the to the `SelectedValue` property and also set the `SelectedValuePath` property:

```
<ComboBox
       SelectedValue="{Binding PropertyName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
       SelectedValuePath="Content">
    <ComboBoxItem Content="AS">
    </ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem Content="ASA">
    </ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem Content="ANS">
    </ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem Content="EPF">
    </ComboBoxItem>
</ComboBox>
```

Comment: Thank you!!!! I changed it as you suggested for both of the ComboBoxes, and it now works! Endorphines firing off now lol. Darned ComboBoxes!!

Answer (score 1):

You have `SelectedItem="{Binding PropertyName}">`

but SelectedItem is of Type ComboBoxItem.

<strike>You want `SelectedValue="{Binding PropertyName}">`</strike>

You can bind to ComboBox.Text instead:

```
 Text="{Binding PropertyName, Mode=OneWayToSource}" >
```

Comment: Thank you for clarifying that. It still doesn't show up after I change it.
Could there be issues due to me using ComboBoxItems? I'd rather not do the work-around suggested by Selvin, as I would prefer to just hard code these values in the XAML, instead of creating a new list or collection for them.

Comment: Yes, you're right. SelectedValue still is a ComboBoxItem. I'll try something.

Comment: Thank you, again! I believe I needed to add some more context, so I updated my question. Please, if you don't mind, have a look :-)